# Function to get the ratio of the number of positive, negative, and null values inside an array in relation to its length

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function that checks what's the ratio of the number of positive, negative and null values inside an array in relation to its length.
The code I wrote is the following:

```
function plusMinus(arr) {

    /**first I declare 3 variables to store the positive, negative and null elements inside them*/

    let numPositive = [];
    let numNegative = [];
    let numZero = [];

    /**then I write a loop that will check whether 
    the elements of the input array are positive, negative or null,
    e.g. if the element[i] is positive, then the array 
    numPositive pushes the positive element[i] inside it, 
    and so on for the rest of the numbers and arrays*/

    for (let i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
        if (arr[i]>0){
            numPositive.push(arr[i]>0);
        }else if (arr[i]<0){
            numNegative.push(arr[i]<0);
        }else{
            numZero.push(arr[i]==0)
        }
    }

    /**finally, the ratios are given as a result of 
    the length of the pushed arrays and the length of the original array*/

    console.log(numPositive.length/arr.length);
    console.log(numNegative.length/arr.length);
    console.log(numZero.length/arr.length);
}
```

I'd like receive some feedback on why my code's logic doesn't work.

Comment: You could just count the elements in each class and use the count instead of saving three sub arrays and get their lengths

Comment: Can you explain little bit more here along with few sample inputs and outputs. Also, does the array made entirely of numbers only? You mentioned `positive, negative and null values` but in the loop, you are checking only for positive and negative values. Everything else will go in the third loop (null, 0). There might be the issue.